# What is the value of OOP in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop

As a C++ developer from the 90s during the great OOP wars, I put high value to OOP as a basis for hiring new C# developers into the company.

However, there are plenty of frameworks today like ASP.NET MVC that handles most of the OOP heavy lifting. Programmers without deep knowledge of OOP can just as easily follow the paradigm and still be able to complete their projects. OOP may not be as compelling as it was before for us application developers, especially with a framework like MVC.

I can see a few instance where OOP will be really handy, like for example developing a workflow type of a project. Or those with state-machine requirements. But really, most projects that really come by (at least to us here anyway) are just CRUD functionalities.

Below is my list when hiring. Is it fair to have OOP there as the number one item?

1. OOP and Design
2. Server side programming: C#, ASP.NET MVC and EF
3. Client side programming: JQuery, CSS, HTML, etc.
4. Database design

Comment: this is probably going to be closed here, you _may_ have more luck on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, but they have as of late started closing opinion based questions as well.

Comment: @BlackICE, thanks for the link. I was hoping for something like that.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't really have anything to do with OOP (Nor does ASP.NET itself) - OOP is at the language level (e.g. C#)

Answer (score 1):

OOP-thinking indicates, that candidate is good at project-architecture. You always need to implement some reusable components, classes, functions, and of course libraries. From my point of view, it is must have for any candidate to know OOP and Design Patterns to be hired.

Comment: I fail to see where you come up with a correlation between OOP and project architecture.